# How to differentiate an executable sh file, and a source sh file?

Tags: shell, filenames, conventions

I have `sh` files that are executable, and others that are only meant to be `source`d by executable ones.

On the executable ones I use no extension at all, and have the first line as `#! /bin/sh`.

On the sourced files, I use `.sh` extension, and they have no first line.

I would like to follow common conventions, but I haven't found any.  Is there any common convention I should follow on those sourced files?

Comment: May be you don't want to have the executable permission (`x`) on sourced ones.

Comment: Of course I don't. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're following something pretty close to the [google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml).

> File Extensions
>   Executables should have no extension (strongly preferred) or a .sh extension. Libraries must have a .sh extension and should not be executable.